# Preact/React and setting state after fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch, preact

My calls to `setState` are doing nothing in the `then` of a `fetch`.

The class is declared like this:

```
export default class QuestionHolder extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      completed:            false,
      revealAnswer:         false,
      selectedAlternative:  undefined,
      submitting:           false,
      explanation:          'philosophy',
    }

    console.log('props', props)
    console.log('state', this.state)
  }
```

```
    fetch(`/questions/${this.question.id}/submit`, {
      method:   'POST',
      headers:  {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          chosen:       this.state.selectedAlternative.id,
          }),
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log('data', data)
        console.log('state before', this.state)
        this.setState({
          explanation: 'phil says so'
        })
        console.log('state after', this.state)
      })
```

The `fetch` works fine (returns `data` and a 200 etc etc - this is legacy code I am updating), but the calls to `console.log` show that `this.state` never changes from the values set in the constructor.

Comment: Updating state is asynchronous, and you are trying to access updated state immediately after state updating. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069332/8936579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State updates [may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) and reading it immediately after setting it will not provide the correct result.

The right place to check for state change is either to pass callback as second argument to `setState` method

```
  this.setState({
      explanation: 'phil says so'
    },() => {
      console.log('Set the explanation state successfully')
    })
```

or using [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle method.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
  if (prevState.explanation !== this.state.explanation) {
    console.log('Set the explanation state successfully')
  }
}
```